# Unable to launch RStudio using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon

Tags: rstudio, linux-mint

I am attempting to start rstudio on a Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit. I'm working remotely using ssh and X11. All other graphical applications work fine so I'm fairly certain that this is not the problem.
I have R installed and it works fine.
Error Information:

Description of issue -
There is no error message. I write "rstudio" on the terminal, nothing happens for a couple of seconds and then I get a new prompt. RStudio silently fails to launch.

Attempted steps taken to fix -
I have uninstalled and installed both R and RStudio with no success.
I have also changed my ~/,profile file so to add:
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
and sourced the file (I followed online instructions from a forum). It didn't work.
System Information:

```
RStudio Edition: Desktop
RStudio Version: 1.1.456
OS Version: 64-bit
R Version: 3.2.3
Output your diagnostics report (if possible):
[1] "1.1.456"

$R
[1] "/usr/bin/R"

$pdflatex
[1] ""

$bibtex
[1] ""

$gcc
[1] "/usr/bin/gcc"

$git
[1] "/usr/bin/git"

$svn
[1] "/usr/bin/svn"

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.1

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3

SysInfo:
sysname
"Linux"
release
"4.4.0-53-generic"
version
"#74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016"
nodename
"mario-xeon"
machine
"x86_64"
login
"paulafp"
user
"paulafp"
effective_user
"paulafp"

R Version:
_
platform x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch x86_64
os linux-gnu
system x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major 3
minor 2.3
year 2015
month 12
day 10
svn rev 69752
language R
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname Wooden Christmas-Tree
$_
[1] "/usr/bin/rstudio"

$CLICOLOR_FORCE
[1] "1"

$DISPLAY
[1] "localhost:10.0"

$EDITOR
[1] "vi"

$GATK
[1] "/home/tjs23/app/GenomeAnalysisTK-3.7/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar"

$GIT_ASKPASS
[1] "rpostback-askpass"

$HOME
[1] "/home/paulafp"

$LANG
[1] "en_GB.UTF-8"

$LANGUAGE
[1] "en_GB:en"

$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[1] "/usr/lib/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server"

$LESSCLOSE
[1] "/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"

$LESSOPEN
[1] "| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"

$LN_S
[1] "ln -s"

$LOGNAME
[1] "paulafp"

$LS_COLORS
[1] "rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:.
tar=01;31:.tgz=01;31:.arc=01;31:.arj=01;31:.taz=01;31:.lha=01;31:.lz4=01;31:.lzh=01;31:.lzma=01;31:.tlz=01;31:.txz=01;31:.tzo=01;31:.t7z=01;31:.zip=01;31:*
.z=01;31:.Z=01;31:.dz=01;31:.gz=01;31:.lrz=01;31:.lz=01;31:.lzo=01;31:.xz=01;31:.bz2=01;31:.bz=01;31:.tbz=01;31:.tbz2=01;31:.tz=01;31:.deb=01;31:.rpm=01;3
1:.jar=01;31:.war=01;31:.ear=01;31:.sar=01;31:.rar=01;31:.alz=01;31:.ace=01;31:.zoo=01;31:.cpio=01;31:.7z=01;31:.rz=01;31:.cab=01;31:.jpg=01;35:.jpeg=01;3
5:.gif=01;35:.bmp=01;35:.pbm=01;35:.pgm=01;35:.ppm=01;35:.tga=01;35:.xbm=01;35:.xpm=01;35:.tif=01;35:.tiff=01;35:.png=01;35:.svg=01;35:.svgz=01;35:.mng=01
;35:.pcx=01;35:.mov=01;35:.mpg=01;35:.mpeg=01;35:.m2v=01;35:.mkv=01;35:.webm=01;35:.ogm=01;35:.mp4=01;35:.m4v=01;35:.mp4v=01;35:.vob=01;35:.qt=01;35:.nuv=
01;35:.wmv=01;35:.asf=01;35:.rm=01;35:.rmvb=01;35:.flc=01;35:.avi=01;35:.fli=01;35:.flv=01;35:.gl=01;35:.dl=01;35:.xcf=01;35:.xwd=01;35:.yuv=01;35:.cgm=01
;35:.emf=01;35:.ogv=01;35:.ogx=01;35:.aac=00;36:.au=00;36:.flac=00;36:.m4a=00;36:.mid=00;36:.midi=00;36:.mka=00;36:.mp3=00;36:.mpc=00;36:.ogg=00;36:.ra=00
;36:.wav=00;36:.oga=00;36:.opus=00;36:.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"

$MAIL
[1] "/var/mail/paulafp"

$MAKE
[1] "make"

$meanGenomeCoverage
[1] "/home/paulafp/cross_filter/meanGenomeCoverage.R"

$OLDPWD
[1] "/home/paulafp"

$PAGER
[1] "/usr/bin/pager"

$PATH
[1] "/home/paulafp/bin:/home/paulafp/.local/bin:/home/tjs23/app/bbmap/:/home/tjs23/app/freebayes/vcflib/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bi
n:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

$PICARD
[1] "/home/tjs23/app/picard.jar"

$plot_heatmap_coverage
[1] "/home/paulafp/cross_filter/plot_heatmap_coverage.R"

$PWD
[1] "/usr/bin"

$QT_IM_MODULE
[1] "compose"

$R_BROWSER
[1] "xdg-open"

$R_BZIPCMD
[1] "/bin/bzip2"

$R_DOC_DIR
[1] "/usr/share/R/doc"

$R_GZIPCMD
[1] "/bin/gzip -n"

$R_HOME
[1] "/usr/lib/R"

$R_INCLUDE_DIR
[1] "/usr/share/R/include"

$R_LIBS_SITE
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library"

$R_LIBS_USER
[1] "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"

$RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
[1] "/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/mathjax-26"

$R_PAPERSIZE
[1] "letter"

$R_PAPERSIZE_USER
[1] "a4"

$R_PDFVIEWER
[1] "/usr/bin/xdg-open"

$R_PLATFORM
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$R_PRINTCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/lpr"

$R_RD4PDF
[1] "times,inconsolata,hyper"

$R_SESSION_TMPDIR
[1] "/tmp/RtmpsN4Pua"

$R_SHARE_DIR
[1] "/usr/share/R/share"

$RS_LOCAL_PEER
[1] "/tmp/19503-rsession"

$RS_PPM_FD_READ
[1] "10"

$RS_PPM_FD_WRITE
[1] "11"

$RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH
[1] "/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rpostback"

$RS_SHARED_SECRET
[1] "16816927778469308861804289383"

$RSTUDIO
[1] "1"

$RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR
[1] "256"

$RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH
[1] "80"

$RSTUDIO_PANDOC
[1] "/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc"

$RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
[1] "19503"

$RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
[1] "paulafp"

$RSTUDIO_WINUTILS
[1] "bin/winutils"

$R_SYSTEM_ABI
[1] "linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?"

$R_TEXI2DVICMD
[1] "/usr/bin/texi2dvi"

$R_UNZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/unzip"

$R_ZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/zip"

$SED
[1] "/bin/sed"

$SHELL
[1] "/bin/bash"

$SHLVL
[1] "1"

$SnpEff
[1] "/home/tjs23/app/snpEff/snpEff.jar"

$SnpSift
[1] "/home/tjs23/app/snpEff/SnpSift.jar"

$SSH_CLIENT
[1] "10.21.96.151 60964 22"

$SSH_CONNECTION
[1] "10.21.96.151 60964 10.21.96.175 22"

$SSH_TTY
[1] "/dev/pts/0"

$TAR
[1] "/bin/tar"

$TERM
[1] "xterm-256color"

$USER
[1] "paulafp"

$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
[1] "/run/user/1002"

$XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
[1] "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4-1537348042.373736-1790440416"

$XDG_SESSION_ID
[1] "2"
[1] ".GlobalEnv" "tools:rstudio" "package:stats"
[4] "package:graphics" "package:grDevices" "package:utils"
[7] "package:datasets" "package:methods" "Autoloads"
[10] "package:base"
Log file: rdesktop.log

(Empty)
Log file: rsession-paulafp.log

(Empty)
```

#

Here is what is printed on the screen when I run diagnostics:

```
paulafp@mario-xeon /usr/bin $ rstudio --run-diagnostics

Using R script: /usr/bin/R

Attempting to launch R session...
R_HOME=/usr/lib/R
R_DOC_DIR=/usr/share/R/doc
R_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/share/R/include
R_SHARE_DIR=/usr/share/R/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server
PATH=/home/paulafp/bin:/home/paulafp/.local/bin:/home/tjs23/app/bbmap/:/home/tjs23/app/freebayes/vcflib/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
HOME=/home/paulafp

R session launched, attempting to connect on port 19503...

Connected to R session, attempting to initialize...

Successfully initialized R session.

Diagnostics report written to: /home/paulafp/rstudio-diagnostics/diagnostics-report.txt

QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
```

Thanks in advance helping me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Rstudio also on Linux Mint
I also purged the Rstudio installation and reinstalled:
The problem persisted ... :(

I found out that I had a project file WITHOUT the sourcecode !
I had copied the source to another place , but actually moved it by mistake
As soon as I made sure that the source code  was in the correct place,
Rstudio worked again after a restart

Perhaps you have the same problem
regards
Golem